# Erro ao pressionar Alt+Tab utilizando pyHook

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando em um script em python que captura teclas digitadas pelo usuário. Para isso, utilizei o módulo pyHook. Entretanto, utilizando o programa, percebi que toda vez que o usuário pressiona Alt+Tab, um erro ocorre.
A versão simplificada que sintetiza a parte do meu programa na qual o erro ocorre é a seguinte:

```
import pyHook,pythoncom
def teclado(event):
    print(event.Key)
    return True

hm=pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown=teclado
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

O código mostra perfeitamente todas as teclas digitadas, porém, ao pressionar Alt+Tab, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'vk_code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'win_name'
```

E o programa se encerra. Como posso evitar esse erro preservando a função do Alt+Tab no windows?

Comment: Não conheço o PyHook. Mas procurando no StackOverflow em inglês eu achei uma informação de que pode ser um erro diretamente no código original. A resposta existente sugere uma possível solução que envolve alterar e recompilar o PyHook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156633/pythoncom-crashes-on-keydown-when-used-hooked-to-certain-applications

Comment: Li tudo mas não entendi o que o cara propôs. Porém, fui visitando links relacionados e acabei descobrindo esse link: https://github.com/Answeror/pyhook_py3k. Nele, tem uma suposta correção para o problema do pyHook. Só que não consegui installar porque não sei o que é a parte "path-to-swig.exe" da instalação. Se você descobrir como instala, pode adicionar uma resposta com esse link ensinando a instalar. Ai se funcionar, eu aceito. @luiz

Comment: Sobre o Swig: http://www.swig.org/. Sinto muito, colega, mas eu não tenho condições de correr atrás disso. Além do que, essa dificuldade de instalação seria outra pergunta, se fizesse parte do escopo do site (instalação de software não faz parte do escopo aqui - tente no [su]).

Comment: Não sabia que Swig era um software. Como você me falou, baixei ele e consegui instalar o pyHook corrigido. Testei e o problema sumiu. Obrigado pelo seu tempo. @luiz

Comment: Ah, por nada. :) Nesse caso, crie você mesmo uma resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é um erro no próprio script do pyHook. Uma solução para esse problema é instalar um pyHook modificado encontrado  [aqui](https://github.com/Answeror/pyhook_py3k). Para instalar, é necessário fazer o download do Swig [aqui](http://www.swig.org/).

Instalação:

1. Abra o cmd
2. Desistale seu pyHook atual com o comando: pip uninstall pyHook
3. Pelo cmd, viaje até a pasta extraída do pyHook corrigido baixado (pyhook_py3k-master)
4. Digite o comando: python setup.py build_ext --swig=path-to-swig.exe
5. Após o sucesso, digite: pip install .

Obs: path-to-swig.exe é o caminho até o arquivo swig.exe, encontrado dentro da pasta baixada pelo site do Swig.